# unable to save looped data from excel in cakephp

Tags: php, excel, loops, cakephp

```
$inputFileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];       
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
            $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

            $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
            $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

            $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5
            $Player_name = '';
            $Activity_name = '';
            $Domain_id = '';
            $Activity_description = '';
            $Activity_date;
            $player_id_owner = '';
            $DomainCount = '';
            echo '<table>' . "\n";
            for ($row = 5; $row <= $highestRow -1; ++$row) 
            {
              echo '<tr>' . "\n";

              for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) 
              {
                echo '<td>' . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";


                $Domain_name = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();                                       
                $Activity_name = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();                                     
                $Activity_description = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $Player_name = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue();                       
                $Activity_date = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getFormattedValue();

            echo '</tr>' . "\n";

            echo '</table>' . "\n";

            }

                $playerCount = $this->PlayerCount($Player_name);
                echo "Current player name is: ".$Player_name;
                echo "Current player count is: ".$playerCount;


                if($playerCount == 0)
                {
                    $email = str_replace(' ', '', "$Player_name@nsn.com");
                    $player_type_id = 2;
                    $password = "password123";


                    $this->Activity->create('Player');
                    $this->request->data['name'] = $Player_name;
                    $this->request->data['player_type_id'] = $player_type_id;
                    $this->request->data['email'] = $email;
                    $this->request->data['password'] = $password;
                    if ($this->Player->save($this->request->data)) 
                    {
                        $this->flashSuccess(__('Player saved successfully!'. $Player_name));
                        echo ("Player saved successfully!". $Player_name);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->flashError(__('Error while trying to save Player.'));
                        debug($this->Activity->validationErrors);
                    }

                }


                $color = "#99CCFF";
                $abbr = "TD";
                $description = $Domain_name;
                $player_type_id = 1;
                $player_id_owner = $this->findPlayerId($Player_name);
                //$player_id_owner = $this->Activity->findId($Player_name);
                //echo h($id = $player_id_owner['Player']['id'] );
                //debug($player_id_owner);                      

                echo "Current Domain name is: ".$Domain_name;
                $domainCount = $this->DomainCount($Domain_name);
                echo "Current Domain count is: ".$domainCount;
                if($domainCount == 0)
                {
                    $inactive = 0;
                    $this->Activity->create('Domain');
                    $this->request->data['name'] = $Domain_name;
                    $this->request->data['color'] = $color;
                    $this->request->data['abbr'] = $abbr;
                    $this->request->data['icon'] = 'fa fa-bolt';
                    $this->request->data['description'] = $description;
                    $this->request->data['player_type_id'] = $player_type_id;
                    $this->request->data['player_id_owner'] = $player_id_owner['Player']['id'] ;
                    $this->request->data['inactive'] = $inactive;
                    if ($this->Domain->save($this->request->data)) 
                    {
                        $this->flashSuccess(__('Domain saved successfully!'. $Domain_name));
                        echo ("Domain saved successfully!". $Domain_name);
                        } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->flashError(__('Error while trying to save domain.'));
                        debug($this->Activity->validationErrors);
                    }
                }


                $activityCount = $this->ActivityCount($Activity_name);
                echo "Current activity name is: ".$Activity_name;
                echo "Current Activity count is: ".$activityCount;

                if($activityCount == 0)
                {
                $Domain_id = $this->findDomainId($Domain_name);
                //debug($Domain_id);
                $this->Activity->create('Activity');
                $this->request->data['name'] = $Activity_name;
                $this->request->data['domain_id'] = $Domain_id['Domain']['id'];
                $this->request->data['description'] = $Activity_description;
                $this->request->data['inactive'] = 0;
                $this->request->data['new'] = 1;
                $this->request->data['xp'] = 100;
                $Activity_date = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($Activity_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss');
                $this->request->data['created'] = $Activity_date;
                $this->request->data['reported'] = 0;
                $this->request->data['player_id_owner'] = $player_id_owner['Player']['id'];
                $this->request->data['acceptance_votes'] = 1;
                $this->request->data['rejection_votes'] = 1;
                if ($this->Activity->save($this->request->data)) 
                {
                    $this->flashSuccess(__('Activity saved successfully!'. $Activity_name));
                    echo ("Activity saved successfully!". $Activity_name);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $this->flashError(__('Error while trying to save activity.'));
                    debug($this->Activity->validationErrors);
                }
            }       
        }
```

I have this function that reads and save domain, activity and player from an excel file. when the excel file contains only 1 row, it functions well, but if the excel contains more than 1 file, only the last row are save but all the activities from all rows are saved, i tried to debug it, i echo every loop and it reads all the row and i try to insert an echo after the saving method to know if it success and it works but when i check it in database, only the last line are saved but the activities are all saved. Kindly help me on this thanks.

[image: This is the sample excel data]

[image: This is the sample activity saved in database, all rows were save]
[image: this is the sample domain only the last row was save]
[image: This is the sample player only the last row was save also]

Answer (score 0):

## Reset the model with $this->Activity->clear();

As the CakePHP book [states](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array):

> When calling save in a loop, don’t forget to call clear().

The `clear` method resets the model before saving the data. If you do not use `clear()`, the ID of the saved row is still in the model, thus the next call to `save` overwrites the previously saved row.

See the [CakePHP book on the `clear` method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-clear):

> This method can be used to reset model state and clear out any unsaved data and validation errors.